# Is there a get_post(s) filter that can alter/replace the output completely?

Tags: filters, get-posts, cache, json

I would like to create a plugin that creates a JSON cache of saved/updated data. But for the plugin to be general purpose I'd need it to override the output of `get_posts` and other `get_functions`.

I know that html cache is faster and that good plugins already exist for that purpose, but this would be a nice thing to have when building a SPA, and in scenarios where table locking occurs like in Woo Commerce sites.

There are hooks like `updated_post_meta` and `post_updated` but I couldn't find the `get_posts filter`. There is `pre_get_posts` but it only allows for the `$args` modification, the underlying `WP_Query` is still ran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look towards the end of the [query process](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_posts/) (which starts with the `pre_get_posts` filter), there is a filter called [`the_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_posts/) (not to be confused with `the_post`). This allows you to modify the output of `get_posts` completely, as you asked.

Beware that this only works if there is no plugin or so that suppresses filters on `get_posts`. Also note that this doesn't work on [`get_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/).